# Script that scans IP range and gets user information to Excel sheet. Recycles information

Tags: excel, vbscript, ip, network-scan

I need help with a VBS script that produces an Excel sheet with specific user information.

It works... Sort of. The problem is that it seems to recycle information producing inaccurate results. Anybody know how I would go about making the script leave areas in the Excel document blank when no information is available? I know it's possible, just need a nudge in the right direction.

Thank you!

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim FSO
Dim objStream

Const TriStateFalse = 0
Const FILE_NAME = "Users.csv"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objStream = FSO.CreateTextFile(FILE_NAME, _
True, TristateFalse)

strSubnetPrefix = "192.168.1."
intBeginSubnet = 1
intEndSubnet = 254

For i = intBeginSubnet To intEndSubnet
strComputer = strSubnetPrefix & i
    'strcomputer = inputbox("Enter Computer Name or IP")
    if strcomputer = "" then
        wscript.quit
    else

    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strcomputer & "'")
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) or objStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then 
            'request timed out
            'msgbox(strcomputer & " did not reply" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
                    '"Please check the name and try again")
        else

            set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
            For Each objComputer in colSettings 
                                    objStream.WriteLine objComputer.name & "," & objcomputer.username & "," & objcomputer.domain _
                & "," & strcomputer
                'msgbox("System Name: " & objComputer.Name & vbcrlf & "User Logged in : " & _
                'objcomputer.username  & vbcrlf & "Domain: " & objComputer.Domain)
            Next
        end if
    next
    end if
Next

Msgbox("Done Collecting")

set objwmiservice = nothing
set colsettings = nothing
set objping = nothing
```

Comment: Hard to tell from you snippet, but could it be that you are not re-setting your object before populating it with new data?  If you don't clear out the old data, it will be retained.

Answer (score 0):

You use the EVIL global `On Error Resume Next`. That means: all errors are ignored/hidden and the script continues (more or less happily) in a for all practical purposes undefined state. Demo script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim a : a = Array(1,0,2)

Bad a
Good a

Sub Bad(a)
    Dim i, n
   On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
        n = 4712 / a(i)
        WScript.Echo "Bad", i, a(i), n
    Next
End Sub

Sub Good(a)
    Dim i, n
    For i = 0 To UBound(a)
      On Error Resume Next
        n = 4712 / a(i)
        If Err.Number Then n = "value to use in case of error"
      On Error GoTo 0
        WScript.Echo "Good", i, a(i), n
    Next
End Sub
```

output:

```
cscript oern.vbs
Bad 0 1 4712
Bad 1 0 4712  <--- assignment failed, 'old' value of n retained, no clue about problem
Bad 2 2 2356
Good 0 1 4712
Good 1 0 value to use in case of error
Good 2 2 2356
```

The strictly local OERN makes sure that the specific problem (division by zero, ping failure) is dealt with, and **all other exceptions** are reported, so the program can be improved.

[further food for thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21902931/603855)

Answer (score 0):

Your WMI call variables need to be reset to nothing before you set them again. This script should work better.

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim FSO
Dim objStream

Const TriStateFalse = 0
Const FILE_NAME = "Users.csv"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objStream = FSO.CreateTextFile(FILE_NAME, _
True, TristateFalse)

strSubnetPrefix = "192.168.1."
intBeginSubnet = 1
intEndSubnet = 254

For i = intBeginSubnet To intEndSubnet
strComputer = strSubnetPrefix & i
    'strcomputer = inputbox("Enter Computer Name or IP")
    if strcomputer = "" then
        wscript.quit
    else

    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
        ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strcomputer & "'")
    For Each objStatus in objPing
        If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) or objStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then 
            'request timed out
            'msgbox(strcomputer & " did not reply" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & _
                    '"Please check the name and try again")
        else

            set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
        strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
            Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")
            For Each objComputer in colSettings 
                                    objStream.WriteLine objComputer.name & "," & objcomputer.username & "," & objcomputer.domain _
                & "," & strcomputer
                'msgbox("System Name: " & objComputer.Name & vbcrlf & "User Logged in : " & _
                'objcomputer.username  & vbcrlf & "Domain: " & objComputer.Domain)
            Next
            set objwmiservice = nothing
            set colsettings = nothing
        end if
    next
    end if
    set objping = nothing
Next

Msgbox("Done Collecting")
```