# Variable in For Loop Retains Old Value

Tags: vbscript, foreach, wmi

I have a program that reads hostnames from a txt file, it scans the network for the hostname and then it displays the hostname and its respective Windows Operating system (CAPTION).

I am trying to get all Windows XP machines upgraded to Windows 7.  I am trying to run this list to give me an idea of how many machines that I have upgraded and an idea of how many I still have to upgrade, etc.

The problem is that when I use the statement `On Error Resume Next` if the script tries to contact a hostname which is a BAD HOST or if the hostname is DOWN it displays the operating system from the last hostname.  Then each and every name that is scans moving forward all shows that same operating system.

What might be causing this error?

```vb
On Error Resume Next

const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile= objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("C:\users\bh\desktop\hostnames.txt", ForReading)

strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.close

arrComputers = Split(strText, vbCrlf)

for Each strComputer in arrComputers
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

    For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings 
        Wscript.Echo strComputer & ": " & objOperatingSystem.Caption
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Global `On Error Resume Next` is just asking for desaster - all errors will be ignored, assignment won't be done as you expect and [stale data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24685438/603855) will be used.

This:

```
Dim aErr

arrComputers = Split(". winxpsp3 nix")

for Each strComputer in arrComputers
  On Error Resume Next
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
  On Error Goto 0
   If 0 = aErr(0) Then
      Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
      For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings
          Wscript.Echo strComputer & ": " & objOperatingSystem.Caption
      Next
  Else
    WScript.Echo "can't reach", strComputer, "error:", Join(aErr)
  End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 30223065.vbs
.: Microsoft Windows XP Professional
winxpsp3: Microsoft Windows XP Professional
can't reach nix error: 462 The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
```

demonstrates a strictly local error handling (max one risky operation between OERN and OEG0) for your first risky task. You'll have to guard/wrap the others accordingly or check return values.

(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21902931/603855) for a strategy for global error handling)